# スパムとみられるユーザ登録（○○○Car Insurance）

Tags: サポート

ユーザを通報する手段はないと思われるので、こちらに投稿します。
以下の複数のアカウントがこの2日間に登録され、いかにもスパムと思われます。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26417/online-car-insurance-calculato
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26414/royal-bank-avion-rental-car-in
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26413/multiple-car-accident-insuranc
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26412/classic-car-insurance-cost
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26411/tell-different-types-of-car-in
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26409/state-farm-car-insurance-comme
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26403/advice-on-car-rental-insurance
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26401/antique-car-insurance-reviews
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26399/high-risk-car-insurance-burlin
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26397/third-party-car-insurance-comp
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26396/one-day-car-insurance-tesco
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26395/jubilee-car-insurance-tanzania
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26393/hit-and-run-insurance-parked-c
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26391/cibc-visa-aerogold-car-rental
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26388/churchill-car-insurance-mobile
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26387/ford-focus-st-show-car-insuran
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26386/detroit-michigan-car-insurance
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26385/allianz-malaysia-car-insurance
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26383/business-car-insurance-for-any
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26382/car-insurers-not-on-compare-we
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26381/lloyds-tsb-car-insurance-landl
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26380/american-family-car-insurance
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26378/diamond-car-insurance-review-u
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26376/car-rental-insurance-costco-am
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26375/australian-unity-car-insurance

Comment: 「初めまして」のバッジ取得者から抽出してきただけなので、他にもあるかもしれません。
 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ここに挙げられているアカウントは、ひとまず破棄いたしました。

なお、本トピックは、 Meta.StackExchange ([Spam Profiles are getting my goat. Could we have better tools for mods to deal with profile spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303746/301070)) でも議論されている様子です。

Comment: ご対応ありがとうございました。現時点でプロフィール以外に実害のある動きはないので、プロフィールを逐一消すためにモデレータの手をわずらわせるべきでない、システム的にうまいこと隠せば良い、という考えが支持されているようですね(?)。私も同感です。

Comment: リンク先にも回答としてありましたがプロフィールの表示が権限の1つになれば良い感じですね。